# Medical Record Database

Tags: database-design

I am new to this forum and new to DB design; i'm a surgeon by profession, live a developing country so have few commercial options but desperately want to have a database which would help me and patients to have a better record of activities. I am avidly reading books about database design especially in MS Access and can improve upon if provided support.
Following is the database design that i'm looking at:
I want a database to store my patients basic demographic info, record their visits which could end in either an admission to the hospital for treatment, or called for further follow-up after performance of certain investigations which could be blood labs or radiology or both or patients may discharged for no further follow-up. On each visit either their clinical features are recorded or their investigations are recorded (which were previously advised). Also needed is their planned surgery date or past surgery details entry.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to ask a question. You should be very familiar with your country's privacy laws and other regulations related to storing and processing private medical information -- properly securing medical record databases can be non-trivial.

Comment: You don't mention your exact country, but I imagine there are legal concerns for patient data. Before you store a single piece of medical data, consult a lawyer to ensure you are not violating one or, more likely, many laws with a project like this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your kind of question is a little broad / general for what is usually applicable to this forum, but hopefully given the circumstances (and holiday :), it is scrutinized a little less. (A candidate question for this forum is usually very objective, specific, and about a particular issue with sufficient details on what was tried so far.)

So it sounds like you just need a way to do basic record keeping, which is a simple use case for most database systems (really almost any tool can accomplish this). But there are a couple minor recommendations I'll make as follows:

1. MS Access was originally designed to be a basic functioning database system but it is very dated, and doesn't have much of a community around it. So while you can probably get started quickly with it, in the long run you might be better off with an alternative solution because as you encounter issues or get stuck, it'll be more difficult to find answers and help.
2. Given your circumstances, I assume you aren't looking to spend a lot of money on a database system, so enterprise systems like Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle PL/SQL are probably **not** something you want to look into either (although they provide a lot of great functionality, you probably won't need 75% of those features).
3. Caveat to #2, Microsoft does offer a [free version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) of their database system with a few limitations. [Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). The main limitation that would likely apply to your case is the total size of the database can't exceed 10 GB. Depending on how many patients you typically see, 10 GB might be plenty of space for a small database, or it may not be.
4. Given #1, #2 and #3, my recommendation would be to use either [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/). Both are highly used, highly capable, and free database management systems that don't impose the same limitations as #3. The benefit of sticking to something highly used is that there's strong communities around them who can help you as you get stuck on a particular issue while trying to setup the database and run queries against it. There might be slightly more work upfront getting either setup as opposed to MS Access, but in the long run the support behind those database systems will be a lot more beneficial to you.

Comment: I second the recommendation on using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't know that it being a holiday is any reason to be more lax for otherwise off-topic (too broad, tip of the iceberg, etc.) questions.

Comment: Apologies for giving a broad open question on this forum but being new and getting frustrated thought to get something and thank you very much for such a detailed, comprehensive answer and for taking your time for the purpose. I won't be recording pt identifiable details so won't be getting into legal problems hopefully. I will look into the links provided by J.D.:)

Comment: @us_man No worries. You may want to familiarize yourself with how to [not ask questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on DBA.SE. Open ended questions may be a better fit for another forum or the [SQL community slack](https://sqlcommunity.slack.com/messages/).

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnMcCall Every rule has flexibility to be bent. I think it's ok to look the other way today (with reminder of what is normally appropriate, as both you and I have communicated now. ;)

Comment: @us_man No problem! I've added my email address to my profile, feel free to reach out if you need any further help (or obviously on here as well when you have more specific questions). I'll do my best to assist.

Comment: @us_man - Hi and welcome to the forum! Oracle also has a free to use version (XE), but if I were you, I would go with PostgreSQL - by far and away the most capable of the F/LOSS systems out there! It also runs well on modest hardware!